# Arrow of Arrow Set is a Functor?

Tags: category-theory

My question is whether arrows between arrows (or arrows in $\bf{Set}^{\rightarrow}$) are, by definition, functors who, in the general sense, map from $\bf{Set}$ to itself.

The definition of a functor is...
For categories **C**, **D** and a functor $F: \bf{C}\rightarrow \bf{D}$, then $F$:

- associates each object $x\in \bf{C}$ an object $F(x)\in \bf{D}$
- associates each arrow $f: x\rightarrow y$ in **C** an object $F(f): F(x)\rightarrow F(y)$ in **D** such that identities and composition are preserved.

An arrow in $\bf{Set}^{\rightarrow}$ takes one function $f: x\rightarrow y$ to another function $g: w\rightarrow z$, which are both in $\bf{Set}$. Since identities and composition must be preserved within a category, then any arrow in $\bf{Set}^{\rightarrow}$ will also preserve identities and composition both in terms of $\bf{Set}^{\rightarrow}$ and in terms of $\bf{Set}$ by acting on the arrows (that also preserve identities and composition) in $\bf{Set}$.

I can't see a contradiction here. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see how you are defining your candidate functor. Given an arrow $f$ in $ {\text{Set}}^{\to}$, you should be able to answer the following questions: Which is the image of a given set $S$? Which is the image of a given map $m:S\to S'$ between sets? If the answer to these questions is not clear, then it is complicated to understand if you are defining a functor or not...

Comment: I had a feeling I was confused. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A category needs *both* objects and arrows. In fact, it is quite common to actually forget about the objects of a category, so we work simply need arrows. All I want to say is that the arrows of a category *should be defined before anything else*.

Given a category $\mathbf{C}$, we can define its *category of arrows*, which you denote $\mathbf{C}^\rightarrow$, but is more commonly denoted $\mathbf{C}^2$. For this, we *need* to define the arrows in $\mathbf{C}^2$ (and the objects, if possible). It does not make sense to ask what are the arrows in $\mathbf{C}^2$, since they should be explicitly defined beforehand.

So, *by definition*: the **objects** of $\mathbf{C}^2$ are arrows of $\mathbf{C}$; Given two objects $f,f'$ in $\mathbf{C}^2$, i.e., two arrows $f:a\to b$, $f':a'\to b'$ in $\mathbf{C}$, an **arrow** $f\to f'$, in $\mathbf{C}^2$, is a pair $(g,h)$ of arrows in $\mathbf{C}$, with $g:a\to a'$ and $h:b\to b'$, satisfying $hf=f'g$. This is the same as the followin diagram commuting
\begin{array}{rcc}
a&\overset{\small f}{\longrightarrow}&b\\
{\small{g}}\left\downarrow\vphantom{\int}\right.&&\left\downarrow\vphantom{\int}\right.{\small{h}}\\
a'&\underset{\small{f'}}{\longrightarrow}&b'
\end{array}

Arrows, and objects, do not need to satisfy any property (other than having a composition, etc...). We usually think of functors as morphisms between categories (i.e., they preserve their structure/composition), so functors work as arrows in the category $\mathbf{Cat}$ of all categories. This is very different from arrows between arrows.

Comment: I find your notation very easy to confused with $C\times C$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson If $2$ denotes the poset $\bullet\to\bullet$, then the functor category $\mathbf{C}^2$ is isomorphic to the one described in the answer. So I am simply giving preference to functor categories over product categories.

Comment: This is also more-or-less consistent to taking $k$-paths of graphs: Given $k$, if we see it a the poset $\bullet\to\bullet\to\cdot\bullet$ with $k$ elements, the objects of $\mathbf{C}^k$ are all sequences $(f_1,\ldots,f_{k-1})$ of composible arrows of $\mathbf{C}$. (although, in graph theory, this would be denoted $\mathbf{C}^{k-1}$). The arrows of $\mathbf{C}^k$ also have some graph-theoretical interpretation.

Comment: I agree that there is a possible consistent interpretation, just not that yours is the most common one,

Answer (score 2):

An arrow between arrows $f,g$ is just a commutative square, so two arrows $h,k$ such that $hf=gk$. In particular, only four sets are involved, whereas a functor on the category of sets must choose an image for every single set. There's no relationship, unless I misread you.